# HashSet.contains returns false when it shouldn't

Tags: java, hash, equals, hashcode, hashset

I have this code:

```
public class Tray {

private Set<Block> blocks;

private int numColumns;
private int numRows;

//constructor
public Tray (int numRows, int numColumns){
    this.numColumns = numColumns;
    this.numRows = numRows;
    blocks = new HashSet<>();
}

public boolean satisfiesGoal(Tray other){

    Block thisBlock = this.blocks.iterator().next();
    Block otherBlock = other.blocks.iterator().next();

    boolean hashesEqual = thisBlock.hashCode() == otherBlock.hashCode(); // this is true

    boolean areEqual = thisBlock.equals(otherBlock) && otherBlock.equals(thisBlock); // this is true

    boolean contains = this.blocks.contains(otherBlock); // this is false, why?
    return contains;
}
```

In the main method I have added the 2 Blocks to their respective Trays.  According to the debugger, the variables "hashesEqual" and "areEqual" are true, but the boolean "contains" is false.  Any ideas as to why the hashes of 2 objects would be equal as well as equal according to the "equals" method, but would not contain the equal object in a HashSet?

Comment: Use a debugger and step into the contains method

Comment: Is this happening to you all the time? I mean, it looks like you built this example specifically for debugging, you're comparing the first item from both sets, and this just happens?  What are these Blocks and where did the other Tray come from?  Are there other Threads involved in this application?  What does your testing method look like that calls "satisfiesGoal()"?

Comment: Does the `Block` class override `hashCode()` and `equals()`? and is it immutable?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This problem happens if you modify the objects in a way that affects their equality and hash codes **after** adding them to the HashSet. The set will malfunction because the objects are not found in the correct slot of the hash table corresponding to their new value.

Likewise, a HashMap will malfunction if you modify objects used as *keys*. Similarly with TreeSet and TreeMap. All these data structures can locate objects quickly because each object's value dictates its storage location. The structure becomes wrong if those objects are then modified.

Immutable objects are nicer as set elements and map keys because they avoid this complication.

If you must modify fields that are part of an object's equality, you'll need to temporarily remove it from the set first, and add it again afterwards. Or, use a list as the main container for your objects, and construct a temporary set only when needed.

Answer (score 3):

Are Block objects mutable?

HashSet stores its contents as keys in a HashMap, with an arbitrary Object as the value.

[As per this article,](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05273/#N10172)

> If an object's hashCode() value can change based on its state, **then we must be careful when using such objects as keys in hash-based collections** [*emphasis mine*] to ensure that we don't allow their state to change when they are being used as hash keys. All hash-based collections assume that an object's hash value does not change while it is in use as a key in the collection. If a key's hash code were to change while it was in a collection, some unpredictable and confusing consequences could follow. This is usually not a problem in practice -- it is not common practice to use a mutable object like a List as a key in a HashMap.

Answer (score 1):

The code for `contains` in openjdk is pretty simple - it eventually just calls [`HashMap.getEntry`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) which uses the hash code and equals to check if the key exists. My guess is that your error is in thinking that the item is in the set already. But you could easily confirm that that is wrong by directly declaring a `Set` in the code you have posted and adding the items to that collection.

Try adding the following unit test:

```
Set<Block> blocks = new HashSet<>();
blocks.add(thisBlock);
assertTrue(thisBlock.hashCode() == otherBlock.hashCode() && thisBlock.equals(otherBlock));
assertTrue(blocks.contains(otherBlock));
```

If the first assertion passes and the second fails then you've found a bug in Java. I find that pretty unlikely.

Also make sure you have the openjdk source code available so you can step into Java methods while debugging. That way you can step into `contains` and check exactly where it is failing.

Also note that your code `this.blocks.iterator().next()` creates a new iterator each time the function is called and then returns the first item in the iteration. In other words it picks the first item in the set (note that this is not the least by natural order). If you are trying to iterate through the two sets in sequence and compare values then that's not what your code does at the moment.

Comment: For me `this.blocks.iterator().next()` makes sense, it's just a simple way of saying _pick first_. This question is a puzzle.

Comment: Ok fair enough. I'll remove that part of my answer.