# Spring Data JPA - Deleting a child in one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing

I'm implementing a Spring boot application and using Spring Data JPA in it. As you know you don't have to implement the repository interface for just CRUD methods, because Spring Data JPA creates an implementation on the fly. So I have just this:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {}
```

I'm working with one-to-many relationship, this is in my Person domain:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy = "person")
private Set<Contact> contacts = new HashSet<>();
```

I decided to write an integration test for child removal from the parent:

```
    @Test
    public void removeFromContacts() {
    // given
    Person person = new Person ("test person");       
    Contact contact = new Contact("test@gmail.com", "+123456789");
    contact.setPerson(person);
    person.getContacts().add(contact);

    personRepository.save(person);

    Person savedPerson = personRepository.findOne(person.getId());
    Contact persistedContact = savedPerson.getContacts().stream().findFirst().orElse(null);

    // when
    savedPerson.getContacts().remove(persistedContact);
    persistedContact.setPerson(null);
    Person edited = personRepository.save(savedPerson);
    // then

    Assert.assertTrue(edited.getContacts().isEmpty());
}
```

This test fails. The reason is `savedPerson.getContacts().remove(persistedContact)` line doesn't change anything, `remove` method returns false. It's pretty strange, because I'm trying to remove an object from a hash set which has only one object with exact same hash code (`equals()` method returns true as well). According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43554123/5718409) answer the contact object could've been altered somehow after adding it to the hash set. The only thing I can think of is it happened after this line: `personRepository.save(person)`.

If I'm right then I'm really confused: how should I remove the contact from a person, and even if I find a way, is it okay for `personRepository.save` method to cause a set to malfunction? And if I'm wrong I would love to know the right answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if that's the problem, but try saving with a `TestEntityManager` instead of your Repository's `save`. Spring Data Repositories don't flush the entities right away

Comment: @SrThompson just tried that, `remove` method still returns false.

Comment: Since the `@OneToMany` is mapped by `person` on the contact record, doesn't this mean that a persisted person doesn't actually have a field for contacts? I believe you need to save the contact (after setting the person to `null`) to erase the relationship

Comment: @Brian I've tried that too, but still, if it's present in `person.getContacts()`, it won't delete

Answer (score 0):

Class Compte and Class User joind to one-to-one relationship

```
public void delete(Integer integer){
    User user = userRepository.findOne(integer);
    Compte compte = user.getCompte();
    compte.setUser(null);
    compteRepository.save(compte);
    user.setCompte(null);
    userRepository.save(user);
    compteRepository.delete(compte);
    userRepository.delete(user);
}
```